# Function not executing in google script HTML service

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am coding a tool for myself and my classmates that will create a google doc and email it to the selected teacher, using all fields that are filled in and filling all those that are not with the defaults for the selected subject, say language arts, but the function that takes the selected information and uses it to send the email is not executing. I've checked the executions for the project, and the function, `customDoc()`, has not once been executed. I suspect it's a problem with my HTML, as I have not seen any error messages when I tested the function in the editor to see if there were any syntax errors, but it was spot clean, just never executed. Here's my code, and while the error is likely in the HTMl I will provide my JS too.

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html');
}

function showDialoge() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html'), 'Test');
}

function customDoc(clicked_id) {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = (d.getDate()) + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
  console.log(s);
  var cycler = clicked_id
  var math = ['esmith3@op97.org', 'math for ']
  var LA = ['cborah@op97.org', 'la for ']
  var science = ['lgrimaldi@op97.org', 'science for ']
  var is = ['charrington@op97.org', 'I&S for ']
  var span = ['vlagioia@op97.org', 'Espanol para ']
  var presets = [math, LA, science, is, span]
  var email1 = document.getElementById('Email')
  var subject1 = document.getElementById('Sub')
  var docName1 = document.getElementById('docName')
  var message1 = document.getElementById('message')
  var email = null
  if (email1 != ' ') {
    email = email1
  } else {
    email = presets[cycler];
    [1];
  }
  var subject = null
  if (subject1 != ' ') {
    subject = subject1
  } else {
    subject = presets[cycler];
    [2]; + s
  }
  var doc = null
  if (docName1 != ' ') {
    doc = docName1
  } else {
    doc = presets[cycler];
    [2]; + s
  }
  var document = documentApp.create(doc)
  var url = document.getUrl();
  var message = null
  if (message1 != ' ') {
    message = message1 + '' + url
  } else {
    message = url
  }

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="Code.gs"></script>
<html>
<h1>CREATE DOC</h1>

<body>


</body>
<p>Email</p>
<input type='text' id='Email' value=' ' style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width:20px; ">
<p style=" font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;">Doc name</p>
<input type='text' id='docName' value=' ' style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width:20px; ">
<p>Subject</p>
<input type='text' id='Sub' value=' ' style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width:20px; ">
<p>message</p>
<input type='text' id='message' value=' ' style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width:20px; ">

<h2>Fill blanks for subject: </h2>


<button id='2' onclick=c ustomDoc(this.id)> LA </button>
<button id='3' onclick=c ustomDoc(this.id)> Science </button>
<button id='4' onclick=c ustomDoc(this.id)> Individuals and societies </button>
<button id='5' onclick=c ustomDoc(this.id)> Spanish  </button>
<button id='1' onclick=c ustomDoc(this.id)> math </button>


</html>
```

Comment: `.getElementByid() !== .getElementById()`

Comment: should this be in my js file?

Comment: No, what he wanted to tell you is, that `getElementByid` does not exist. Instead use `getElementById`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. Well to be fair, he could have said it a little bit more clearly.

Comment: I fixed the typo with the getElementById but it still doesn't work

Comment: Fair enough, I'll accept that criticism if you will accept this criticism as well - your code is a complete and utter mess. No `;` spacing is silly, indentation and formatting is ridiculous. :-)

Comment: Any idea why the function isn't calling?

Comment: So, what is this? `documentApp.create(doc)` - I don't see an object named `documentApp` with a function named 'creaet()` declared in your code. But, I do see an error in the console that says `document` is undefined.

Comment: By maintaining better code standards your code quality will increase significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, `customDoc()` is a server function and you need to use `google.script.run` to tell Apps Script to run a specific server function. So instead of calling `onclick="customDoc(this.id)"`, try `onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)"`. Don't include Code.gs in your HTML file as that's server-side code and it won't work. I highly recommend reading the [Client-to-Server Communication guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Your `customDoc()` function is another story :) Below is a very simple way to reorganize your different presets (e.g. subjects) using [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). I also replaced your date formatting code with [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format), which may be a little easier to comprehend.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html');
}

function customDoc(subject) {
  var subjects = {
    'math': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'math for '
    },
    'la': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'la for '
    },
    'science': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'science for '
    },
    'is': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'I&S for '
    },
    'spanish': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'Español para '
    }
  };

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'M/d/yyyy');
  
  console.log('Today: ' + formattedDate);
  console.log('Subject: ' + subject);
  console.log(subjects[subject]);
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>CREATE DOC</h1>
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="text" id="Email" value=" " style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width: 20px" />
    
    <p style="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif">Doc name</p>
    <input type="text"  id="docName" value=" " style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width: 20px" />
    
    <p>Subject</p>
    <input type="text" id="Sub" value=" " style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width: 20px" />
    
    <p>message</p>
    <input type="text" id="message" value=" " style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width: 20px" />

    <h2>Fill blanks for subject:</h2>

    <button id="la" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">LA</button>
    <button id="science" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">Science</button>
    <button id="is" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">Individuals and societies</button>
    <button id="spanish" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">Spanish</button>
    <button id="math" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">math</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try running the above and clicking the science button. You should get an execution log like:

```
Today: 10/30/2020
Subject: science
{preSubject=science for , email=teacher@example.com}
```

Now that `customDoc()` is actually executing, you can start trying to fix the Google Doc generation. It seems to me that you're creating a completely blank Google Doc, which probably isn't what you want. I think you need to work on it some more and then come back if you have more specific questions about generating the document. Good luck!

Comment: Well, now what's happening is the recipient is either not defined, or when I define it says unexpected identifier.

Comment: @LlamaButt How are you referring to the recipient?

Comment: Have you inputted a good email address in your input field? I think the main problem will be that you are not passing the email address you input to the Apps Script function you run when you click the button. Could you try and pass it as a paramter of the ```customDoc()``` function and let me know how that goes? Thanks !