# Need variable A to declare variable B, but need variable B to declare variable A

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am making a tool to make a new google doc and email it to my teacher for a certain subject, however my variable "Subjects" needs to include the document link, which means I need to create the document before I declare the variable Subjects, however in order to know what to name the doc, I need to access information stored in the variable Subjects. Any suggestions? My javascript is down below.

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html');
}

function customDoc(subject) {

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'M/d/yyyy');
  
  var subjects = {
      'math': {
     email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'math for '
    },
    'la': {
     email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'la for '
    },
    'science': {
     email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'science for '
    },
    'is': {
  email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'I&S for '
    },
    'spanish': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      preSubject: 'Español para '
    
      message:  'Español para ' + formattedDate + 'This is supposed to be where the link to the google doc is, so this is where the paradox comes in. '
    }
  };

 
  console.log('Today: ' + formattedDate);
  console.log('Subject: ' + subject);
  console.log(subjects[subject]);
GmailApp.sendEmail(subjects.email, subjects.preSubject, subjects.message)
}
```

Comment: So you want to call doGet? It is unclear exactly what you need to call.

Comment: I want to include the link to the document in the variable subjects, but I need the information stored in subjects in order to name the document.

Comment: So reference the object, pass it to whatever makes the document, alter the object with that data.

Comment: Referring to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613579/function-not-executing-in-google-script-html-service), you're trying to pass the value from the `docName` text box in your HTML to `customDoc()`, correct? If so, could you please update this question to clarify that?

Comment: This question is about the logic of your program flow.  You are assigning a value to the variable `subjects` that is an object literal.  All that means is that you are creating the object by typing the object as text to your code.  Once that object is created you can modify it later.  But it's pointless to add a key/value element to the object if all you are going to do is retrieve the value later in the same function.   You can assign the Doc file ID to another variable, and use that variable later.   You haven't shown how the file name will be constructed from the object values.

Comment: I don't think I understand your predicament. `subjects` is a variable: what's stopping you from adding the document link later? Also, could you clarify what information from `subjects` do you need in order to name the corresponding doc?

Comment: you're right. I could easily add the document link later.

Comment: If you already found the solution for this, post it as answer, otherwise [edit] the question to clarify what was being asked in the previous comments.