# Get value of a text entry box without using document.getElementById() in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, getelementbyid

I am creating a tool that uses google apps script html service to create a page that will create a new google doc for the selected subject, using the values in the text entry box if they have been edited, and using the default value for the selected subject if not, however I can't use document.getElementById(), and I was wondering if there were any alternatives. My code is down below.

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html');
}

function customDoc(subject) {

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'M/d/yyyy');
 var la=['teacher@example.com','LA for '+ formattedDate]
  var math=['teacher@example.com', 'math for '+ formattedDate]
 var spanish=['teacher@example.com','Espanol para ' +formattedDate]
var science = ['teacher@example.com','science for '+formattedDate]
var is = ['teacher@example.com','I&S for '+formattedDate]
var cycle= [la, science, is, spanish, math]
var e = null  
var d = null
var s = null
var m = null
if (Document.getElementById('Email') === ' '){
  e=cycle[subject][1]   }
 
  else {e=Document.getElementById('Email')}

  if (Document.getElementById('docName') === ' '){
  d=cycle[subject][2]   }
 
  else {d=Document.getElementById('docName')}

  if (Document.getElementById('Sub') === ' '){
  s=cycle[subject][2]   }
 
  else {s=Document.getElementById('Sub')}

 if (Document.getElementById('message') === ' '){
   m = ' '}
  else {m=Document.getElementById('message')}

var doc = DocumentApp.create(d)
var doccu = doc.getUrl();
var body = m + '    ' + doccu
   GmailApp.sendEmail(e, s, body)
console.log(e);
  console.log(s);
  console.log(body);
  console.log(doccu);
  console.log(d);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>CREATE DOC</h1>
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="text" id="Email" value=" " style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width: 20px" />
    
    <p style="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif">Doc name</p>
    <input type="text"  id="docName" value=" " style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width: 20px" />
    
    <p>Subject</p>
    <input type="text" id="Sub" value=" " style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width: 20px" />
    
    <p>message</p>
    <input type="text" id="message" value=" " style="border-radius: 20px; border-color: crimson; border-width: 20px" />

    <h2>Fill blanks for subject:</h2>

    <button id="1" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">LA</button>
    <button id="2" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">Science</button>
    <button id="3" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">Individuals and societies</button>
    <button id="4" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">Spanish</button>
    <button id="5" onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)">math</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use getElementByID, or you aren't using it correctly to grab the value? The proper way to get the value of an input field is: `document.getElementById('id').value`

Comment: Ohhhhh. I'll try that and let you know if it works. Thank you!

Comment: yeah, something is still not working.

Comment: You can't use document.getElementById() server side.

Comment: You can pass the value in a text box using google.script.run from client to server.  Google Script run on the server.  Document.getElementById() is a client side javascript function.  You have already been told this in your first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a client-side function, so it needs to be within your HTML. (Remember that `customDoc()` is a server-side function.)

You can call `document.getElementById('docName')` to get the doc name text box, and then access its `value` property to get the text that's inside the text box. Then you can pass this value along with the subject name to `customDoc()`.

Follow the same approach for getting the other text box values from your HTML inputs.

In my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64617679/1329498) to your original question, I decided to repeat `onclick="google.script.run.customDoc(this.id)"` for clarity. Now there are other steps you need to take before calling `customDoc()`, so it's better to call an intermediary function. Instead of specifying `onclick` for each button, you can add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to all of the buttons. So anytime a button is clicked, the intermediary `getValuesAndCreateDoc()` function is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    input {
      border-radius: 20px;
      border-color: crimson;
      border-width: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>CREATE DOC</h1>
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="text" id="Email">
    
    <p style="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif">Doc name</p>
    <input type="text"  id="docName">
    
    <p>Subject</p>
    <input type="text" id="Sub">
    
    <p>message</p>
    <input type="text" id="message">

    <h2>Fill blanks for subject:</h2>

    <button id="la">LA</button>
    <button id="science">Science</button>
    <button id="is">Individuals and societies</button>
    <button id="spanish">Spanish</button>
    <button id="math">math</button>
    
    <script>
      // Run getValuesAndCreateDoc() when a button is clicked
      const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
      for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', getValuesAndCreateDoc);
      }
      
      /**
       * Get the user values and create the document.
       * @param {Event} event
       */
      function getValuesAndCreateDoc(event) {
        const clicked = event.target.id;
        const email = document.getElementById('Email').value.trim();
        const docName = document.getElementById('docName').value.trim();
        const sub = document.getElementById('Sub').value.trim();
        const message = document.getElementById('message').value.trim();
        console.log('Clicked: ' + clicked);
        console.log('Email: ' + email);
        console.log('Doc Name: ' + docName);
        console.log('Sub: ' + sub);
        console.log('Message: ' + message);
        google.script.run.customDoc(clicked, email, docName, sub, message);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html');
}

function customDoc(clickedId, email, docName, sub, message) {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'M/d/yyyy');
  var classes = {
    'math': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      docName: 'math for ' + formattedDate
    },
    'la': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      docName: 'la for ' + formattedDate
    },
    'science': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      docName: 'science for ' + formattedDate
    },
    'is': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      docName: 'I&S for ' + formattedDate
    },
    'spanish': {
      email: 'teacher@example.com',
      docName: 'Español para ' + formattedDate
    }
  };
  
  var selectedClass = classes[clickedId];
  
  // Set defaults
  if (email == '') {
    email = selectedClass.email;
  }
  if (docName == '') {
    docName = selectedClass.docName;
  }
  if (sub == '') {
    sub = clickedId;
  }
  if (message == '') {
    message = 'Default message';
  }
  
  console.log('Today: ' + formattedDate);
  console.log('Clicked ID: ' + clickedId);
  console.log('Email: ' + email);
  console.log('Doc Name: ' + docName);
  console.log('Sub: ' + sub);
  console.log('Message: ' + message);
  
  // Create the Google Doc
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
  
  // Send the email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, sub, message + '    ' + doc.getUrl());
}
```

Comment: When I try to save the file it says unexpected token 'class', line 30

Comment: @LlamaButt `class` is a reserved word in the [V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime). I had been using the older Rhino runtime. (If you don't know it, don't worry.) I edited my code to use `selectedClass` instead, so it should save now.

Comment: kay, fixed that up. No problem's now, except that I woke up the dog and he started barking his head off when  I screamed "YES, IT WORKS" at the top of my lungs as I have been tinkering with this program for a few months now, always finding another snag as soon as I think I am done. So thank you SO much.